# Need help for understanding Cython -find an example but doesn't working

Tags: python, cython

I have a problem for understanding Cython and pxd. I have find this code on internet but doesn't working. Can you explain me why ?

The error when I compile:

> warning: test.pyx:1:0: Overriding cdef method with def method.
>
> test.pxd:6:14: C method 'foo' is declared but not defined

I find this example here : https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html

I have do an error into the compilation ?

compile.py :

```py
import os
import sysconfig

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

fichier = "test.pyx"

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(fichier)
)
```

test.pyx :

```py
def myfunction(x, y=2):
    a = x - y
    return a + x * y

def _helper(a):
    return a + 1

class A:
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = b

    def foo(self, x):
        print(x + _helper(1.0))
```

test.pxd :

```py
cpdef int myfunction(int x, int y=*)
cdef double _helper(double a)

cdef class A:
    cdef public int a, b
    cpdef foo(self, double x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the filename. `.pyx` files are dealt with as Cython files (i.e. they have to match the `.pxd` files). However `.py` files are interpreted as "pure Python mode" (since they also have to work in Python).

If you rename your `.pyx` file to `.py` it will work.

---

This is stated pretty clearly in the documentation you linked to:

> While declarations in a .pyx file must correspond exactly with those of a .pxd file with the same name (and any contradiction results in a compile time error, see pxd files), the untyped definitions in a .py file can be overridden and augmented with static types by the more specific ones present in a .pxd

Comment: Thank you very much. That do 5 hours than I search and I have read quickly the page... I'm stupid, if a take time to read slowly all !!! ;o)